# Decryption of an mp4

Tags: mpeg-dash, playready, widevine

Is there a way I can decrypt a file that I downloaded? Originaly it was mpd file but I downloaded mp4 using dash downloader. I can see KID, com.widevine.alpha X-AxDRM-Message and com.microsoft.playready X-AxDRM-Message.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this file is encrypted as you say, and that two different DRM systems are available to decrypt the content and play it back: PlayReady and Widevine.

If you are asking can you get the key outside of these DRM systems and decrypt the file yourself, then the answer is probably going to be no as typically if the content provider goes to the trouble of using a DRM they won't also supply the key separately.

If you just want to know if these DRM's support 'download and go' playback of encrypted movies, then the answer is that they both have options for this. You will typically have to have subscribed to or bought the right to view the content to view it.